# Server side state management in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, state, session-state, application-state

I'm working on a distributed application that runs on Windows Azure, but I'm new of this kind of environment. I have a question about server-side state management.
Where should I store global almost static data?

Because it is a distributed environment if a user makes a request to the application, there is no guarantee that subsequent requests will be routed to the same server and so I think that I should use Sql Azure or Table Storage Session Provider (but I've read that can be performance issues) to store the data.

I can also use Windows Azure AppFabric Caching that enables session maintenance.

What is the better solution to store global information that don't need to be secured? Is there something similar to "Application" (like Application["key"] = value)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my responses on the following thread:

[Microsoft Azure .NET 4.5 WebForms App : Session TimeOut / InProc / Single Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659436/microsoft-azure-net-4-5-webforms-app-session-timeout-inproc-single-instan/33660981#33660981)

Specifics are below:

> If you want to maintain session state you have to use one of the
>   following options
>
> - SQL Session State Provider using Azure SQL
> - Azure Table Session State
> - Session State with Azure Redis Cache
>
> You can find details on how to do this at the following links:
>
> - [Session State Management in Windows Azure Web Roles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2013/05/17/session-state-management-in-windows-azure-web-roles.aspx)
> - [Session state with Azure Redis cache in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-session-state-caching/)
>
> The easiest way in my opinion is using Azure Redis Cache as noted in
>   the link above.
>
> Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Why didn't you just mark this question as a duplicate of the one you answered?

Comment: I was not aware I have the ability to do that. Am I able to remove my answer and do this?

Comment: Well... I went back and read the question you had answered. While your answer there applies to this question, it doesn't really apply to the other question (and the questions are definitely not duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely at that time perhaps, but now Azure Storage Tables :)